# Express Checkout Return URL C#

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the PayPal API in C# and calling the .SetExpressCheckout() with a return url of:
http://www.MyWebsite.com/Success?transactionId={DynamicToken}

Is it possible that PayPal isn't returning the transactionId token that I have specified or is that improbable? I am trying to diagnose a few random errors (from hundreds of successful transactions) and wondering would it ever drop the parameter I have specified in the Return URL?

Also is it safe to assume that if PayPal returns 'Successful' but I DONT call .DoExpressCheckout() that no money has been taken and I can start again?

Answer (score 0):

SetExpressCheckout will always return a response something like this:

```
NVP Response:
TOKEN=EC-8FL80454MK5202351
TIMESTAMP=2015-09-10T02:53:36Z
CORRELATIONID=bff60e96e81c4
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=000000
```

and you will need to redirect to the checkout page

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8FL80454MK5202351

Once the buyer login and completes, it will redirect to your returnurl+EC-token+payerid

http://index.php?action=ECreturn&token=EC-8FL80454MK5202351&PayerID=7SGRP23PR8MWY

So, PayPal always does return the EC-Token and after this you will need to call Doexpresscheckout API to complete the payment without this the transaction is not complete.

```
VERSION = 109.0
METHOD = DoExpressCheckoutPayment
TOKEN = EC-8FL80454MK5202351
PAYMENTACTION = Sale
PAYERID = 7SGRP23PR8MWY
AMT = 0.01
```

for example if you have a return url like this

```
RETURNURL = index.php?action=ECreturn?test=1
```

then it after Setexpresscheckout is complete, Paypal will redirect to the following URL

```
index.php?action=ECreturn?test=1&token=EC-5K62958L49079615&PayerID=7SGRP23PR8MWY
```

Comment: But if you add an additional parameter to your url, will it always return that? Or is it only guaranteed to return the Payer ID and EC-Token?

Comment: it will return whatever you pass in return url as a query string parameter, updated answer